# Is there a way to change the different dimensions (x,y) of font-size?

Tags: html, css

```
div {
   font-size:1.2em;
}
```

This looks like it changes both the xy coordinates of a font. Is there any way I can independently modify the x and y coordinates of a font?

For example:

```
div {

   font-size-y:1.6em;
   font-size-x:1.2em;
}
```

(this would make the font taller)

Possible, or no?

Comment: There is the font-stretch CSS selectors but they are not very well supported by browsers

Answer (score 3):

There are not font-size-x or font-size-y styling rules. There are however transforms for size, scale and location. You could do something like this to achieve what you want.

```css
div {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.0, 2.0);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 2.0);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: scale(1.0, 2.0);
}
```

```html
<div>
  Hello World
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.  Example only answers do not help the user understand as well as narrated ones.

Comment: Thanks for prompting me. I meant to add an explanation and got a phone call and hit the post button. Bad me :)